# Why isn't setting the height of a html element working using percentages?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a dashboard which is supposed to have three different panels. Each panel width is supposed to be 25% of the screen, which is working. However, I can't manage to set the height of each panel to a certain height using percentages. It seems like no matter how I set the height, it always remains the same (third property in panel class).

Also I'm wondering why I can't set the height of the image container to a certain height. I'd like it to always take up half the space of a panel. But the size of each image container is different for each panel.

Can someone explain to me why that is and how I can fix this?

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.panel {
  /*Basics*/
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 25%;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;

  /*Round corners*/
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;

  /*Slight shadow under the panels*/
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  /*Have panels next to each other*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.panel .image-container {
  /*Position image container relative to parent*/
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

  /*Horizontally cut image in half*/
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel .image-container img {
  /*max-inline-size: 100%;*/
  /*width: 500px;
  height: 200px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
}

.panel .icon-container {
  /*Position image container relative to parent*/
  position: relative;

  /*Position icon in the middle*/
  align-content: center;
  margin: -30px auto auto;

  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.panel .icon {
  /*Position icon in the middle*/
  padding: 23%;
}

.panel p {
  margin: 5% 20%;
}

.panel button {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2% 5%;
  margin: 5%;

  /*Font*/
  color: #FFFFFF;

  /*Round corners*/
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;

  /*Fading out background*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, var(--start-background-color), var(--end-background-color));
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="icon-container">
      <svg class="icon" width="52" height="50" viewBox="0 0 52 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M26.0538 33.3859C34.7207 33.3859 41.7467 26.3599 41.7467 17.6929C41.7467 9.02597 34.7207 2 26.0538 2C17.3868 2 10.3608 9.02597 10.3608 17.6929C10.3608 26.3599 17.3868 33.3859 26.0538 33.3859Z" stroke="#DB0D22" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
        <path d="M2.26123 47.2222C4.67345 43.0151 8.14197 39.5218 12.3183 37.0931C16.4947 34.6644 21.2319 33.3858 26.0539 33.3859C30.8759 33.3859 35.613 34.6646 39.7894 37.0934C43.9657 39.5222 47.4341 43.0156 49.8463 47.2226" stroke="#DB0D22" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-container">
      <p>Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext</p>
      <button>Texttext Texttext</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669299033175-09d02a0031f1?crop=faces%2Cedges&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjg0MTk2MDUyfA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=60&w=1200&auto=format&h=630&mark-w=64&mark-align=top%2Cleft&mark-pad=50&blend-mode=normal&blend-alpha=10&blend-w=1&mark=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fopengraph%2Flogo.png&blend=000000" alt="Image 2">
    </div>
    <div class="icon-container">
      <svg class="icon" width="52" height="52" viewBox="0 0 52 52" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M36.8877 7.75624C37.6377 4.94826 38.8437 2.59225 40.4877 0.692255C40.9577 0.148258 41.6837 -0.101732 42.3896 0.0382672C43.0936 0.178266 43.6696 0.686281 43.8976 1.36828C43.8976 1.36828 43.9356 1.48026 43.9996 1.67626C44.9956 4.66224 47.3376 7.00424 50.3236 8.00023C50.5196 8.06423 50.6315 8.10222 50.6315 8.10222C51.3135 8.33022 51.8216 8.90621 51.9616 9.61021C52.1016 10.3142 51.8535 11.0402 51.3096 11.5102C49.4116 13.1582 47.0596 14.3702 44.2496 15.1202C46.6236 18.8422 47.9996 23.2621 47.9996 28.0001C47.9996 41.2461 37.2457 52 23.9998 52C10.7539 52 0 41.2461 0 28.0001C0 14.7542 10.7539 4.00025 23.9998 4.00025C28.7418 4.00025 33.1637 5.37826 36.8877 7.75624ZM36.1257 12.1002C32.7617 9.52823 28.5578 8.00023 23.9998 8.00023C12.9619 8.00023 3.99997 16.9622 3.99997 28.0001C3.99997 39.0381 12.9619 48 23.9998 48C35.0377 48 43.9996 39.0381 43.9996 28.0001C43.9996 23.5021 42.5116 19.3482 39.9997 16.0062C39.9697 15.9642 39.9396 15.9222 39.9116 15.8782C39.5696 15.9102 39.2217 15.9362 38.8697 15.9582L33.7797 21.0482C35.1777 23.0102 35.9997 25.4101 35.9997 28.0001C35.9997 34.6221 30.6217 40.0001 23.9998 40.0001C17.3778 40.0001 11.9999 34.6221 11.9999 28.0001C11.9999 21.3782 17.3778 16.0002 23.9998 16.0002C26.5898 16.0002 28.9897 16.8222 30.9517 18.2202L36.0437 13.1282C36.0657 12.7802 36.0937 12.4362 36.1257 12.1002ZM28.0638 21.1082C26.8718 20.4042 25.4818 20.0002 23.9998 20.0002C19.5838 20.0002 15.9999 23.5841 15.9999 28.0001C15.9999 32.4161 19.5838 36.0001 23.9998 36.0001C28.4158 36.0001 31.9997 32.4161 31.9997 28.0001C31.9997 26.5181 31.5957 25.1281 30.8917 23.9361L25.4138 29.4141C24.6338 30.1941 23.3658 30.1941 22.5858 29.4141C21.8058 28.6341 21.8058 27.3661 22.5858 26.5861L28.0638 21.1082ZM41.7176 6.09423C40.9396 7.74223 40.4336 9.65821 40.1756 11.8302C42.3516 11.5742 44.2656 11.0682 45.9116 10.2862C44.2296 9.20424 42.7996 7.77423 41.7176 6.09423Z" fill="#DB0D22"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-container">
      <p>Texttext Texttext </p>
      <button>Texttext Texttext Texttext </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="Image 3">
    </div>
    <div class="icon-container">
      <svg class="icon" width="54" height="48" viewBox="0 0 54 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M50.0494 40.099C50.0476 40.3481 50.0311 40.5969 49.9997 40.8441L50.0593 40.4006C50.0212 40.6688 49.966 40.9321 49.8929 41.193C49.8569 41.3212 49.8136 41.4472 49.7685 41.5724C49.7273 41.6865 49.6025 41.9734 49.8183 41.4684C49.7872 41.5411 49.753 41.6124 49.7189 41.6837C49.5944 41.9436 49.4442 42.1905 49.2809 42.4277C49.0374 42.7812 49.5292 42.1313 49.2571 42.4628C49.158 42.5835 49.0514 42.6978 48.9426 42.8098C48.8518 42.903 48.756 42.9912 48.659 43.0779C48.6007 43.13 48.5404 43.1795 48.4799 43.2291C48.2404 43.4257 48.8194 42.975 48.5691 43.158C48.3365 43.328 48.0877 43.4746 47.8319 43.6062C47.7097 43.6691 47.2472 43.8598 47.7983 43.6337C47.6507 43.6943 47.4995 43.7451 47.3474 43.7926C47.0638 43.881 46.772 43.94 46.4782 43.9818L46.9217 43.9221C46.3635 43.993 45.7946 43.9718 45.2328 43.9718H8.15355C7.59175 43.9718 7.02291 43.993 6.46469 43.9221L6.90816 43.9818C6.63998 43.9436 6.37669 43.8884 6.11584 43.8153C5.98762 43.7794 5.8616 43.736 5.73636 43.6909C5.6222 43.6498 5.33531 43.5249 5.84033 43.7407C5.76764 43.7096 5.69632 43.6754 5.62506 43.6413C5.36516 43.5168 5.11819 43.3666 4.88106 43.2033C4.52744 42.9599 5.17742 43.4516 4.84596 43.1795C4.72525 43.0804 4.61085 42.9738 4.49896 42.865C4.40565 42.7743 4.31753 42.6784 4.23084 42.5814C4.17876 42.5231 4.12919 42.4628 4.07962 42.4023C3.88294 42.1628 4.33367 42.7418 4.15064 42.4915C3.98071 42.2589 3.83414 42.0101 3.70246 41.7543C3.6396 41.6321 3.44882 41.1696 3.67493 41.7207C3.6144 41.5731 3.56358 41.4219 3.51609 41.2698C3.42761 40.9863 3.36862 40.6944 3.32692 40.4006L3.3865 40.8441C3.29712 40.1397 3.33687 39.4098 3.33687 38.7013V15.1251C3.33687 14.7387 3.33764 14.3571 3.3865 13.9718L3.32692 14.4153C3.36499 14.1471 3.42016 13.8838 3.49333 13.623C3.52926 13.4948 3.57263 13.3687 3.61774 13.2435C3.65891 13.1293 3.78367 12.8425 3.56792 13.3475C3.59897 13.2748 3.63317 13.2035 3.66731 13.1322C3.79183 12.8723 3.94198 12.6253 4.1053 12.3882C4.34875 12.0346 3.85702 12.6846 4.12913 12.3531C4.22821 12.2324 4.33487 12.118 4.44366 12.0061C4.53435 11.9128 4.63022 11.8247 4.72721 11.738C4.78549 11.6859 4.84584 11.6363 4.9062 11.5868C5.14578 11.3901 4.56676 11.8408 4.81712 11.6578C5.04961 11.4879 5.29849 11.3413 5.55433 11.2096C5.67648 11.1467 6.13907 10.956 5.58794 11.1821C5.73546 11.1215 5.88674 11.0707 6.03886 11.0232C6.32235 10.9348 6.6143 10.8758 6.90798 10.8341L6.46451 10.8936C7.02274 10.8229 7.59157 10.844 8.15337 10.844H45.2327C45.7945 10.844 46.3633 10.8229 46.9216 10.8936L46.4781 10.8341C46.7463 10.8721 47.0096 10.9274 47.2704 11.0004C47.3986 11.0364 47.5247 11.0798 47.6498 11.1249C47.764 11.1661 48.0509 11.2908 47.5459 11.0751C47.6186 11.1061 47.6899 11.1403 47.7611 11.1745C48.021 11.299 48.268 11.4491 48.5051 11.6124C48.8587 11.8559 48.2087 11.3642 48.5402 11.6363C48.6609 11.7354 48.7753 11.842 48.8872 11.9508C48.9805 12.0415 49.0687 12.1374 49.1554 12.2344C49.2074 12.2926 49.257 12.353 49.3066 12.4133C49.5032 12.6529 49.0525 12.0739 49.2356 12.3243C49.4055 12.5568 49.5521 12.8056 49.6837 13.0615C49.7465 13.1836 49.9373 13.6462 49.7112 13.0951C49.7717 13.2426 49.8226 13.3939 49.87 13.546C49.9585 13.8295 50.0175 14.1214 50.0592 14.4151L49.9996 13.9717C50.089 14.6761 50.0493 15.4059 50.0493 16.1145V39.6906C50.0494 39.8269 50.0494 39.9629 50.0494 40.099C50.0494 41.0084 50.8082 41.7673 51.7177 41.7673C52.6272 41.7673 53.386 41.0084 53.386 40.099V14.9891C53.386 14.4701 53.3386 13.9641 53.2652 13.4473C53.0504 11.9331 52.1942 10.4583 51.0766 9.43078C49.6547 8.12361 47.8407 7.50759 45.9276 7.50759H7.35521C5.21621 7.50759 3.09443 8.38047 1.72046 10.0543C0.629214 11.3837 0.0133729 12.9882 0.000503138 14.717C-0.000628923 14.8643 0.000503138 15.0117 0.000503138 15.1589V38.759C0.000503138 39.6441 -0.00390591 40.4868 0.121276 41.3687C0.336189 42.8829 1.19233 44.3578 2.30997 45.3853C3.57531 46.5485 5.16908 47.1842 6.87545 47.2985C7.33298 47.3292 7.79844 47.3085 8.25638 47.3085H45.3497C46.169 47.3085 46.9491 47.2958 47.7666 47.1301C51.033 46.468 53.3617 43.3702 53.386 40.099C53.3927 39.1894 52.6221 38.4307 51.7178 38.4307C50.8032 38.4307 50.0561 39.1896 50.0494 40.099ZM18.8284 7.20962C18.8302 6.95991 18.8466 6.71223 18.878 6.46448L18.8185 6.90795C18.8565 6.63977 18.9117 6.37648 18.9849 6.11563C19.0208 5.98741 19.0642 5.86139 19.1093 5.73615C19.1504 5.62199 19.2752 5.3351 19.0595 5.84012C19.0905 5.76743 19.1247 5.69611 19.1588 5.62485C19.2834 5.36495 19.4335 5.11799 19.5968 4.88085C19.8403 4.52723 19.3486 5.17721 19.6207 4.84576C19.7198 4.72504 19.8264 4.61065 19.9352 4.49875C20.0259 4.40544 20.1218 4.31732 20.2188 4.23063C20.277 4.17856 20.3374 4.12898 20.3977 4.07941C20.6373 3.88273 20.0583 4.33347 20.3087 4.15043C20.5412 3.9805 20.79 3.83393 21.0458 3.70226C21.168 3.6394 21.6306 3.44861 21.0794 3.67473C21.2269 3.61419 21.3782 3.56337 21.5303 3.51588C21.8138 3.4274 22.1058 3.36842 22.3995 3.32671L21.956 3.38629C22.4882 3.31878 23.0268 3.33666 23.5622 3.33666H30.6278C30.8966 3.33666 31.1635 3.35251 31.4303 3.38629L30.9868 3.32671C31.255 3.36478 31.5183 3.41996 31.7791 3.49306C31.9073 3.52905 32.0334 3.57243 32.1585 3.61753C32.2727 3.6587 32.5596 3.78347 32.0546 3.56772C32.1273 3.59876 32.1986 3.63296 32.2698 3.6671C32.5297 3.79163 32.7767 3.94178 33.0138 4.10509C33.3674 4.34854 32.7174 3.85681 33.0489 4.12892C33.1697 4.22801 33.284 4.33466 33.3959 4.44346C33.4892 4.53414 33.5774 4.63001 33.6641 4.72701C33.7161 4.78528 33.7657 4.84564 33.8153 4.90599C34.0119 5.14557 33.5612 4.56655 33.7443 4.81692C33.9142 5.04941 34.0608 5.29828 34.1924 5.55413C34.2552 5.67627 34.446 6.13887 34.2199 5.58773C34.2804 5.73526 34.3313 5.88654 34.3787 6.03865C34.4672 6.32214 34.5262 6.61409 34.5679 6.90777L34.5083 6.46431C34.5397 6.71205 34.5561 6.95967 34.558 7.20944C34.5647 8.11878 35.3117 8.87774 36.2263 8.87774C37.1306 8.87774 37.9013 8.1189 37.8946 7.20944C37.87 3.9009 35.5372 0.889681 32.2751 0.178329C31.5323 0.0163255 30.7951 0 30.0432 0H22.8449C20.0746 0 17.3915 1.52536 16.2105 4.0837C15.7528 5.07539 15.4999 6.11229 15.4917 7.20944C15.485 8.1189 16.2558 8.87774 17.16 8.87774C18.0746 8.87792 18.8216 8.1189 18.8284 7.20962Z" fill="#DB0D22"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-container">
      <p>Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext </p>
      <button>Texttext </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `.panel`s are `10%` of the height of `.wrapper` which has not got a `height` set so is `height: auto` (the default).

`10%` of `auto` is `auto` so the `.panel`s heights are determined by their content.

Comment: @Quentin nope, the wrapper element should be of 100%, and the panel class must not have a height assigned. because then it would still scale to the content, not to the overall available space.

Comment: @muzzletov — You included your CSS in the question. The wrapper element does **not** have a height specified and `.panel` **does**.

Comment: `%` is a unit that is relative to the parent element. That means, `height: 100%` will be 100% of the parent's elements height. However, by default an element's height is `undefined` and calculated to `fit-content`. 1005 od undefined is still undefined!! YOu need a defined parent's height to work.

Comment: @tacoshy — "However, by default an element's height is undefined" — **no**, it is `auto`.

Comment: auto means that by the time it is read it is undefined. It is calculated afterward. But you know that `undefined` is not a valid property for that attribute.

Comment: @Quentin thats not my question. Yes, you forgot to mention that panel should not have a height assigned. That's all that I am saying.

Comment: Ok, I've set the height of the wrapper to 100% and if remove the height attribute of the panel class, their size is at least the same. But how can I determine the height of the panels if I'm not supposed to give them a height attribute?

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing the [flexible box layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). Since the wrapper has `display: flex`, the panels have equal height by default. However, you are constricting the height down to 10% and each panel is overflowing. Remove the height declaration to revert to default equal height.

As is, the `top` declaration for `.panel .image-container img` is skewing the image's height. All you need is 100% width and height on the image, and just the desired height on the container. BTW, declaring `height: 50%` does *not* cut the image in half as your comment suggests.

From my understanding of your question, I believe this example is closer to what you are attempting.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px; /* <- */
}

.panel {
  /*Basics*/
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* width: 25%; */
  /* height: 100%; */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex: 1; /* <- */

  /*Round corners*/
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;

  /*Slight shadow under the panels*/
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  /*Have panels next to each other*/
  /* display: inline-block; */
  /* margin: 10px; */
}

.panel .image-container {
  height: 25%;

  /*Position image container relative to parent*/
  /* position: relative; */
  /* width: 100%; */

  /*Horizontally cut image in half*/
  /* height: 50%; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.panel .image-container img {
  /*max-inline-size: 100%;*/
  /*width: 500px;
  height: 200px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* object-fit: cover; */
  /* position: relative; */
  /* top: -50%; */
}

.panel .icon-container {
  /*Position image container relative to parent*/
  position: relative;

  /*Position icon in the middle*/
  align-content: center;
  margin: -30px auto auto;

  width: 20%;
  height: 10%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.panel .icon {
  /*Position icon in the middle*/
  padding: 23%;
}

.panel p {
  margin: 5% 20%;
}

.panel button {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2% 5%;
  margin: 5%;

  /*Font*/
  color: #FFFFFF;

  /*Round corners*/
  border-radius: 1vmin;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;

  /*Fading out background*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, var(--start-background-color), var(--end-background-color));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="icon-container">
      <svg class="icon" width="52" height="50" viewBox="0 0 52 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M26.0538 33.3859C34.7207 33.3859 41.7467 26.3599 41.7467 17.6929C41.7467 9.02597 34.7207 2 26.0538 2C17.3868 2 10.3608 9.02597 10.3608 17.6929C10.3608 26.3599 17.3868 33.3859 26.0538 33.3859Z" stroke="#DB0D22" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
        <path d="M2.26123 47.2222C4.67345 43.0151 8.14197 39.5218 12.3183 37.0931C16.4947 34.6644 21.2319 33.3858 26.0539 33.3859C30.8759 33.3859 35.613 34.6646 39.7894 37.0934C43.9657 39.5222 47.4341 43.0156 49.8463 47.2226" stroke="#DB0D22" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-container">
      <p>Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext</p>
      <button>Texttext Texttext</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1669299033175-09d02a0031f1?crop=faces%2Cedges&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fHwxNjg0MTk2MDUyfA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=60&w=1200&auto=format&h=630&mark-w=64&mark-align=top%2Cleft&mark-pad=50&blend-mode=normal&blend-alpha=10&blend-w=1&mark=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fopengraph%2Flogo.png&blend=000000" alt="Image 2">
    </div>
    <div class="icon-container">
      <svg class="icon" width="52" height="52" viewBox="0 0 52 52" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M36.8877 7.75624C37.6377 4.94826 38.8437 2.59225 40.4877 0.692255C40.9577 0.148258 41.6837 -0.101732 42.3896 0.0382672C43.0936 0.178266 43.6696 0.686281 43.8976 1.36828C43.8976 1.36828 43.9356 1.48026 43.9996 1.67626C44.9956 4.66224 47.3376 7.00424 50.3236 8.00023C50.5196 8.06423 50.6315 8.10222 50.6315 8.10222C51.3135 8.33022 51.8216 8.90621 51.9616 9.61021C52.1016 10.3142 51.8535 11.0402 51.3096 11.5102C49.4116 13.1582 47.0596 14.3702 44.2496 15.1202C46.6236 18.8422 47.9996 23.2621 47.9996 28.0001C47.9996 41.2461 37.2457 52 23.9998 52C10.7539 52 0 41.2461 0 28.0001C0 14.7542 10.7539 4.00025 23.9998 4.00025C28.7418 4.00025 33.1637 5.37826 36.8877 7.75624ZM36.1257 12.1002C32.7617 9.52823 28.5578 8.00023 23.9998 8.00023C12.9619 8.00023 3.99997 16.9622 3.99997 28.0001C3.99997 39.0381 12.9619 48 23.9998 48C35.0377 48 43.9996 39.0381 43.9996 28.0001C43.9996 23.5021 42.5116 19.3482 39.9997 16.0062C39.9697 15.9642 39.9396 15.9222 39.9116 15.8782C39.5696 15.9102 39.2217 15.9362 38.8697 15.9582L33.7797 21.0482C35.1777 23.0102 35.9997 25.4101 35.9997 28.0001C35.9997 34.6221 30.6217 40.0001 23.9998 40.0001C17.3778 40.0001 11.9999 34.6221 11.9999 28.0001C11.9999 21.3782 17.3778 16.0002 23.9998 16.0002C26.5898 16.0002 28.9897 16.8222 30.9517 18.2202L36.0437 13.1282C36.0657 12.7802 36.0937 12.4362 36.1257 12.1002ZM28.0638 21.1082C26.8718 20.4042 25.4818 20.0002 23.9998 20.0002C19.5838 20.0002 15.9999 23.5841 15.9999 28.0001C15.9999 32.4161 19.5838 36.0001 23.9998 36.0001C28.4158 36.0001 31.9997 32.4161 31.9997 28.0001C31.9997 26.5181 31.5957 25.1281 30.8917 23.9361L25.4138 29.4141C24.6338 30.1941 23.3658 30.1941 22.5858 29.4141C21.8058 28.6341 21.8058 27.3661 22.5858 26.5861L28.0638 21.1082ZM41.7176 6.09423C40.9396 7.74223 40.4336 9.65821 40.1756 11.8302C42.3516 11.5742 44.2656 11.0682 45.9116 10.2862C44.2296 9.20424 42.7996 7.77423 41.7176 6.09423Z" fill="#DB0D22"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-container">
      <p>Texttext Texttext </p>
      <button>Texttext Texttext Texttext </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="Image 3">
    </div>
    <div class="icon-container">
      <svg class="icon" width="54" height="48" viewBox="0 0 54 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M50.0494 40.099C50.0476 40.3481 50.0311 40.5969 49.9997 40.8441L50.0593 40.4006C50.0212 40.6688 49.966 40.9321 49.8929 41.193C49.8569 41.3212 49.8136 41.4472 49.7685 41.5724C49.7273 41.6865 49.6025 41.9734 49.8183 41.4684C49.7872 41.5411 49.753 41.6124 49.7189 41.6837C49.5944 41.9436 49.4442 42.1905 49.2809 42.4277C49.0374 42.7812 49.5292 42.1313 49.2571 42.4628C49.158 42.5835 49.0514 42.6978 48.9426 42.8098C48.8518 42.903 48.756 42.9912 48.659 43.0779C48.6007 43.13 48.5404 43.1795 48.4799 43.2291C48.2404 43.4257 48.8194 42.975 48.5691 43.158C48.3365 43.328 48.0877 43.4746 47.8319 43.6062C47.7097 43.6691 47.2472 43.8598 47.7983 43.6337C47.6507 43.6943 47.4995 43.7451 47.3474 43.7926C47.0638 43.881 46.772 43.94 46.4782 43.9818L46.9217 43.9221C46.3635 43.993 45.7946 43.9718 45.2328 43.9718H8.15355C7.59175 43.9718 7.02291 43.993 6.46469 43.9221L6.90816 43.9818C6.63998 43.9436 6.37669 43.8884 6.11584 43.8153C5.98762 43.7794 5.8616 43.736 5.73636 43.6909C5.6222 43.6498 5.33531 43.5249 5.84033 43.7407C5.76764 43.7096 5.69632 43.6754 5.62506 43.6413C5.36516 43.5168 5.11819 43.3666 4.88106 43.2033C4.52744 42.9599 5.17742 43.4516 4.84596 43.1795C4.72525 43.0804 4.61085 42.9738 4.49896 42.865C4.40565 42.7743 4.31753 42.6784 4.23084 42.5814C4.17876 42.5231 4.12919 42.4628 4.07962 42.4023C3.88294 42.1628 4.33367 42.7418 4.15064 42.4915C3.98071 42.2589 3.83414 42.0101 3.70246 41.7543C3.6396 41.6321 3.44882 41.1696 3.67493 41.7207C3.6144 41.5731 3.56358 41.4219 3.51609 41.2698C3.42761 40.9863 3.36862 40.6944 3.32692 40.4006L3.3865 40.8441C3.29712 40.1397 3.33687 39.4098 3.33687 38.7013V15.1251C3.33687 14.7387 3.33764 14.3571 3.3865 13.9718L3.32692 14.4153C3.36499 14.1471 3.42016 13.8838 3.49333 13.623C3.52926 13.4948 3.57263 13.3687 3.61774 13.2435C3.65891 13.1293 3.78367 12.8425 3.56792 13.3475C3.59897 13.2748 3.63317 13.2035 3.66731 13.1322C3.79183 12.8723 3.94198 12.6253 4.1053 12.3882C4.34875 12.0346 3.85702 12.6846 4.12913 12.3531C4.22821 12.2324 4.33487 12.118 4.44366 12.0061C4.53435 11.9128 4.63022 11.8247 4.72721 11.738C4.78549 11.6859 4.84584 11.6363 4.9062 11.5868C5.14578 11.3901 4.56676 11.8408 4.81712 11.6578C5.04961 11.4879 5.29849 11.3413 5.55433 11.2096C5.67648 11.1467 6.13907 10.956 5.58794 11.1821C5.73546 11.1215 5.88674 11.0707 6.03886 11.0232C6.32235 10.9348 6.6143 10.8758 6.90798 10.8341L6.46451 10.8936C7.02274 10.8229 7.59157 10.844 8.15337 10.844H45.2327C45.7945 10.844 46.3633 10.8229 46.9216 10.8936L46.4781 10.8341C46.7463 10.8721 47.0096 10.9274 47.2704 11.0004C47.3986 11.0364 47.5247 11.0798 47.6498 11.1249C47.764 11.1661 48.0509 11.2908 47.5459 11.0751C47.6186 11.1061 47.6899 11.1403 47.7611 11.1745C48.021 11.299 48.268 11.4491 48.5051 11.6124C48.8587 11.8559 48.2087 11.3642 48.5402 11.6363C48.6609 11.7354 48.7753 11.842 48.8872 11.9508C48.9805 12.0415 49.0687 12.1374 49.1554 12.2344C49.2074 12.2926 49.257 12.353 49.3066 12.4133C49.5032 12.6529 49.0525 12.0739 49.2356 12.3243C49.4055 12.5568 49.5521 12.8056 49.6837 13.0615C49.7465 13.1836 49.9373 13.6462 49.7112 13.0951C49.7717 13.2426 49.8226 13.3939 49.87 13.546C49.9585 13.8295 50.0175 14.1214 50.0592 14.4151L49.9996 13.9717C50.089 14.6761 50.0493 15.4059 50.0493 16.1145V39.6906C50.0494 39.8269 50.0494 39.9629 50.0494 40.099C50.0494 41.0084 50.8082 41.7673 51.7177 41.7673C52.6272 41.7673 53.386 41.0084 53.386 40.099V14.9891C53.386 14.4701 53.3386 13.9641 53.2652 13.4473C53.0504 11.9331 52.1942 10.4583 51.0766 9.43078C49.6547 8.12361 47.8407 7.50759 45.9276 7.50759H7.35521C5.21621 7.50759 3.09443 8.38047 1.72046 10.0543C0.629214 11.3837 0.0133729 12.9882 0.000503138 14.717C-0.000628923 14.8643 0.000503138 15.0117 0.000503138 15.1589V38.759C0.000503138 39.6441 -0.00390591 40.4868 0.121276 41.3687C0.336189 42.8829 1.19233 44.3578 2.30997 45.3853C3.57531 46.5485 5.16908 47.1842 6.87545 47.2985C7.33298 47.3292 7.79844 47.3085 8.25638 47.3085H45.3497C46.169 47.3085 46.9491 47.2958 47.7666 47.1301C51.033 46.468 53.3617 43.3702 53.386 40.099C53.3927 39.1894 52.6221 38.4307 51.7178 38.4307C50.8032 38.4307 50.0561 39.1896 50.0494 40.099ZM18.8284 7.20962C18.8302 6.95991 18.8466 6.71223 18.878 6.46448L18.8185 6.90795C18.8565 6.63977 18.9117 6.37648 18.9849 6.11563C19.0208 5.98741 19.0642 5.86139 19.1093 5.73615C19.1504 5.62199 19.2752 5.3351 19.0595 5.84012C19.0905 5.76743 19.1247 5.69611 19.1588 5.62485C19.2834 5.36495 19.4335 5.11799 19.5968 4.88085C19.8403 4.52723 19.3486 5.17721 19.6207 4.84576C19.7198 4.72504 19.8264 4.61065 19.9352 4.49875C20.0259 4.40544 20.1218 4.31732 20.2188 4.23063C20.277 4.17856 20.3374 4.12898 20.3977 4.07941C20.6373 3.88273 20.0583 4.33347 20.3087 4.15043C20.5412 3.9805 20.79 3.83393 21.0458 3.70226C21.168 3.6394 21.6306 3.44861 21.0794 3.67473C21.2269 3.61419 21.3782 3.56337 21.5303 3.51588C21.8138 3.4274 22.1058 3.36842 22.3995 3.32671L21.956 3.38629C22.4882 3.31878 23.0268 3.33666 23.5622 3.33666H30.6278C30.8966 3.33666 31.1635 3.35251 31.4303 3.38629L30.9868 3.32671C31.255 3.36478 31.5183 3.41996 31.7791 3.49306C31.9073 3.52905 32.0334 3.57243 32.1585 3.61753C32.2727 3.6587 32.5596 3.78347 32.0546 3.56772C32.1273 3.59876 32.1986 3.63296 32.2698 3.6671C32.5297 3.79163 32.7767 3.94178 33.0138 4.10509C33.3674 4.34854 32.7174 3.85681 33.0489 4.12892C33.1697 4.22801 33.284 4.33466 33.3959 4.44346C33.4892 4.53414 33.5774 4.63001 33.6641 4.72701C33.7161 4.78528 33.7657 4.84564 33.8153 4.90599C34.0119 5.14557 33.5612 4.56655 33.7443 4.81692C33.9142 5.04941 34.0608 5.29828 34.1924 5.55413C34.2552 5.67627 34.446 6.13887 34.2199 5.58773C34.2804 5.73526 34.3313 5.88654 34.3787 6.03865C34.4672 6.32214 34.5262 6.61409 34.5679 6.90777L34.5083 6.46431C34.5397 6.71205 34.5561 6.95967 34.558 7.20944C34.5647 8.11878 35.3117 8.87774 36.2263 8.87774C37.1306 8.87774 37.9013 8.1189 37.8946 7.20944C37.87 3.9009 35.5372 0.889681 32.2751 0.178329C31.5323 0.0163255 30.7951 0 30.0432 0H22.8449C20.0746 0 17.3915 1.52536 16.2105 4.0837C15.7528 5.07539 15.4999 6.11229 15.4917 7.20944C15.485 8.1189 16.2558 8.87774 17.16 8.87774C18.0746 8.87792 18.8216 8.1189 18.8284 7.20962Z" fill="#DB0D22"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-container">
      <p>Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext Texttext </p>
      <button>Texttext </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```